# Hightlighted Content webpart - filter based on columns and display content from another site collection

Tags: spfx-webparts, highlighted-content-web-part, third-party-software

I'm working on an intranet build.We have decided to have a dedicated publishing site for News.I would like to display these news content on other sites.

The news webpart is great to do this but the filter options are limited.
What i mean is in the source site(the site with all the news) i have a category field that i would like to filter with from the destination site.
But it doesn't show either the Page Properties ut only the metadata property.
I don't have access toconfigure the metadata properties to use.

Are there any other method to use or a custom webpart in github etc..

Thanks in Advance